# Scope needed to get access token to pull user groups from Azure using client id and client secret and graph API

Tags: azure, scope, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to get the groups in my azure tenant using my client secret and client id. Problem is I don't know what scope to pass when getting an access token to use the graph api. I used https://graph.microsoft.com/.default to get an access token but this doesn't include permission to pull groups. What's the appropriate scope to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0#permissions

> **Permissions**
>
> One of the following permissions is required to call this API. To learn more, including how to choose permissions, see Permissions.
>
> ---
>
> Permission type   Permissions (from least to most privileged)
>
> Delegated (work or school account)    Group.Read.All, Group.ReadWrite.All
>
> Application **Group.Read.All, Group.ReadWrite.All**

You need to configure the API access within AAD, not with the scope. Make sure that you **don't forget to click on "grant permissions"**.

Example assumes that you require application permission. Delegated permission works similarly.

[image]
[image]

Sample code for getting the data using [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet) for authentication:

```
        IConfidentialClientApplication app = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
            "clientId",
            "https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com",
            "http://localhost (redirecturi)",
            new ClientCredential("secret"),
            new TokenCache(), new TokenCache());

        string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        try
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(scopes);
            System.Console.WriteLine(result.AccessToken);

            using (var http = new HttpClient())
            {
                http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
                var groupResponse = await http.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups");
                var groupJson = await groupResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                System.Console.WriteLine(groupJson);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```